# make a reset button for count down timer in swift

Tags: swift, countdowntimer

Hi this is a sample code and there is no reset button in there and I have problem with make a reset button for this count down timer

[Source Link](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/swift-countdown-timer-of-60-seconds)

Comment: please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53847590/edit) your question and post your code using the code formatting in the editor, dont provide external links as some people cannot access them and sometimes links are removed later.

Comment: Add another button. Connect that to your VC file. In this button invalidate the current timer, reset the `totalTime`, and call startTimer again.

Answer (score -1):

If you're new in Swift I advise you this Repository

https://github.com/soapyigu/Swift-30-Projects/tree/master/Project%2002%20-%20Stopwatch

There you have a simple Stopwatch (and 29 more simple Apps) with a intelligible source Code.